# Color Svg elements in html

Tags: html, svg

I am using svg icons in my website, and wanted to change their colors to red (all of them are black in color).

```
<img src='assets/icon.svg'/>
```

I tried using the css fill property on img tag but it doesn't work.
Then I came across the object attr and tried using the svg icon as follows:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/icon.svg"></object>
```

and here on applying fill property on object does nothing. Any ideas on how to change the fill property of svg elements without using jquery

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakks1995/dxzf984s/8/)

Comment: Edit the icon.svg file and change all the colours in the file to red.

Comment: The fiddle you link is using .png image files. You can't change the color of those in code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set fill color to svg path

```
path {
    fill:red;
}
```

Comment: not working by directly adding it to css file, also I don't have a path element I guess as I am importing it externally

Comment: can you share working code snippet?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: please use svg file in fiddle you have used png file. please update fiddle with svg